# my script runs well on firefox but fail on google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, firefox

my script should show the clicked cards one and two. If they compare they should dissapear both. If they dont met they should show the cards-background again. On Google the second card don't show it's frontside. Even if both card get the class .frontside and the right values to compare. This problem only happen on googles chrome. On Firefox there are also no no problems shown in the console.debugger.
I set it online under: [script in action][1]https://obs-design.de/index.php?design=1&mainmenu=games

Is there anyone who sees the bug?

Here is the script:

```
<style>

.containerh1w1{
cursor: pointer;
}
.containerh1w1 img.backside,
.containerh1w1.backside img.backside{
     display:block;
     margin:auto auto;
     object-fit:cover;
     }
.containerh1w1 img.frontside,
.containerh1w1.backside img.frontside{
     display:none;
     }
.containerh1w1.frontside img.frontside{
     display:block;
     margin:auto auto;
     object-fit:cover;
     }
.containerh1w1.frontside img.backside{
     display:none;
     }
.containerh1w1.empty img.backside{
     display:none;
     }
.containerh1w1.empty img.frontside{
     display:none;
     }
#monitor{
     position:absolute;
     z-index:1100;
     top: 0;
     left:0;
     width:210px;
     height:20px; 
     background:#000;
     }
#timerwrapper,
#zugoverviewwrapper{
    float:left; 
    }
#timerwrapper span,
#zugoverviewwrapper span{
    display:inline;
    font-size:0.9rem;
    line-height:20px;
    color:#fff; 
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
    }
#timer{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:20px;
    font-size:1rem;
    line-height:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0 auto;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    float:right;
    margin-right:15px;
}
#zugoverview{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    font-size:1rem;
    line-height:20px;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    text-align:center;
    }
</style>

<script>

shuffledarr = Array;
    var array =[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 21, 24, 30, 33, 39];
    var imgno='';

var zug = 0;
var treffer = 0;
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    var arr;
    shuffledarr = array;
    var sek = 0;

function sec(){
    sek = sek +1;
    document.querySelector('#timer').innerHTML=sek;
    }


function zuege(){
    zug += 1;
    return zug;
    }

function shufflel(no){
    imgno = shuffledarr[no];
    return imgno;
    }   
  
function dataauslesen(no){
    imgno = shuffledarr[no];
    document.querySelector('#field' +no).innerHTML='<img src="games/images/card_'+ imgno +'.gif"    id="bild + no" class="frontside">';
    console.log(shuffledarr);
    }


var firstchoice ='';
var secondchoice ='';
function front(no){
    var elem = document.querySelector('#field' +no);
    elem.classList.remove('backside');
    elem.classList.add('frontside');
    if(firstchoice==''){
        firstno = no;
        firstchoice =shufflel(no);
    } else {
        secondno = no;
        secondchoice = shufflel(no);
        zug = zug + 1;
        document.querySelector('#zugoverview').innerHTML=zug;
    
        if( 3*firstchoice == secondchoice || firstchoice == 3*secondchoice){
           alert("Gratuliere, Treffer");
           document.querySelector('#field'+firstno).classList.remove('backside');
           document.querySelector('#field'+firstno).classList.remove('frontside');
           document.querySelector('#field'+firstno).classList.add('empty');
           document.querySelector('#field'+secondno).classList.remove('backside');
           document.querySelector('#field'+secondno).classList.remove('frontside');
           document.querySelector('#field'+secondno).classList.add('empty');
           }
        else {
           alert("Schade, kein Treffer");
           document.querySelector('#field' +firstno).classList.remove('frontside');
           document.querySelector('#field' +firstno).classList.add('backside');
           document.querySelector('#field' +secondno).classList.remove('frontside');
           document.querySelector('#field' +secondno).classList.add('backside');    
           }

    firstchoice = '';
    firstno='';
    }
secondchoice = '';
secondno='';
}

</script>
<div id="monitor">
    <div id="timerwrapper">
        <span>Sek.:</span>
        <div id="timer"><script>setInterval(sec, 1000)</script></div>
    </div>
    <div id="zugoverviewwrapper">
        <span>Anzahl Zuege:</span>
        <div id="zugoverview"></div></div>
    </div>

<div id="mainwrapper">
    <div id="wrapper1">
        <div id="field0" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(0)">               
            <script>dataauslesen(0)</script>                            
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>  
                
        <div id="field1" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(1)">                       
            <script>dataauslesen(1)</script>    
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />                       
        </div>  
                
        <div id="field2" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(2)">                                       
            <script>dataauslesen(2)</script>        
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />  
        </div>  
                
        <div id="field3" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(3)">                           
            <script>dataauslesen(3)</script>        
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>  
                
        <div id="field4" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(4)">                                   
            <script>dataauslesen(4)</script>        
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" /> 
        </div>  
                
        <div id="field5" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(5)">                                   
            <script>dataauslesen(5)</script>        
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>      
                
        <div id="field6" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(6)">                   
            <script>dataauslesen(6)</script>        
             <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>  
                
        <div id="field7" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;"  onclick="front(7)">                  
            <script>dataauslesen(7)</script>        
             <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>  
                
        <div id="field8" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(8)">                    
            <script>dataauslesen(8)</script> 
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />       
        </div>      
                
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper2">     
    
        <div id="field9" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(9)">       
            <script>dataauslesen(9)</script>
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />       
        </div>      
                
        <div id="field10" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(10)">           
            <script>dataauslesen(10)</script>       
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>  
                
        <div id="field11" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(11)">          
            <script>dataauslesen(11)</script>       
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>      
                
        <div id="field12" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(12)">          
            <script>dataauslesen(12)</script>       
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>  
                
        <div id="field13" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(13)">          
            <script>dataauslesen(13)</script>       
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>  
                
        <div id="field14" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(14)">          
            <script>dataauslesen(14)</script>       
             <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>      
                
        <div id="field15" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(15)">          
            <script>dataauslesen(15)</script>       
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>  
                    
        <div id="field16" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(16)">         
            <script>dataauslesen(16)</script>       
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>  
                
        <div id="field17" class="containerh1w1" style="text-align:center;" onclick="front(17)">          
            <script>dataauslesen(17)</script>   
            <img src="games/images/card_backsite.gif" class="backside" />
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question would deserve some attention (and some further editing to comply with SO standards), but is definitely worth looking into. At first look, I would have expected to find an obvious syntax mistake, but having looked into it it's actually a very interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, the Alert is being displayed before the "frontside" class is successfully added. You should consider using async/await https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Instead of

```
function front(no){
    
    var elem = document.querySelector('#field' +no);    
    elem.classList.remove('backside');
    elem.classList.add('frontside');
    if(firstchoice==''){
        firstno = no;
        firstchoice =shufflel(no);
    } else {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Try something like this

```
function front(no){
    evaluatePairs();        
    ...
}

function updateClasses() {
  return new Promise(() => {
    var elem = document.querySelector('#field' +no);    
    elem.classList.remove('backside');
    elem.classList.add('frontside');
  });
}

async function evaluatePairs() {
    const result = await updateClasses();
    if (result) {
        if(firstchoice==''){
            firstno = no;
            firstchoice =shufflel(no);
        } else {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation why this happens? I'm currently debugging OP's script in chrome, using breakpoints, and when I break between the class being added and the alert being prompted, I can actually see the face of the card I clicked...

Comment: Compare the breaking in Firefox and Chrome. In the exact same step, just before the alert pops up, the element in firefox already has the class "frontside", while in Chrome it's just about to be added. Async exists precisely for this.

Comment: I get what happens. I get why async solves it. I just don't get WHY it happens...  and why chrome behaves differently than Firefox on this. Is chrome so much slower than FF to trigger class change (or faster to trigger alert) that on Chrome the alert gets displayed before class change, blocking script execution and thus class change?

Comment: Thanks for your advice.Anibal
I also believe that the solution lies in async.
I have implemented your code suggestion. Now the front is shown on the 2nd card, but the further script, i.e. the division between the first and second card, is no longer running. No alert either. So I'll have to experiment with async a little more

Comment: Hello. Sorry, Laurent S. I just assumed that the attribute edition (the class changing) performed by Chrome is taking longer than in Firefox (or Firefox is delaying the alert poping). It's just a matter of miliseconds, but it's enough to break your code if you don't successfully control the sequence of events. If it wasn't a class addition but a "setTimeOut", you would have had to place the next alert into its function's scope or the same would have happened.
barfy26, try refactoring your code and encapsuling parts of it in functions/constants for easily handling the chain of events.

Comment: In some cases, I prefer passing parameters to functions whenever I can instead of using the global scope. 'firstchoice' value (for example) could have been handled through a parameter passed to the 'front' function in order to make sure that the value remains the same in the funcions scope, preventing this asynchronous execution issues.